# SUBST for OSX? Error when trying to map local folder as network drive on Mac OSX 10.9

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mavericks, shared-folders, subst

I would like to map a local folder as a drive (similar to Window's SUBST).

One solution I found was to map a shared folder, which would be fine but I get the following error when using a local folder:

**There was a problem connecting to the server “MyDrive.local”.**
This file server is available on your computer. Access the volumes and files locally.

Is it possible to bypass this error and enable access to a local drive?

I was using this guide: [Mapping Drives (Shared Folders) on Mac OS X](https://bmi.cchmc.org/resources/storage-servers/rds/mapping-mac)